# Gradients are not computed with respect to a variable that is stored in a TensorArray

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

For y=x**2 the gradient dy_dx won't be computed if x is retrieved from a TensorArray.

How can I store both the x and y ops in a TensorArray, then retrieve them, and call tf.gradients to compute the gradient?

The use case would be: one builds a while_loop, a bunch of different values (i.e. x,y) are generated within the iteration, they are pushed into TensorArrays, and then outside the loop I would like to get the derivative of one array with respect to another array.

Example illustrating the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.Variable(np.array([3]).astype(np.float32), trainable=False)
y = x ** 2
xa = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1).write(0, x)
ya = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1).write(0, y)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# these work as expected:
print(sess.run(tf.gradients(y, x)))  # stdout: [array([ 6.], dtype=float32)]
print(sess.run(tf.gradients(ya.stack(), x)))  # stdout: [array([ 6.], dtype=float32)]

# why no gradient?
print(tf.gradients(ya.stack(), xa.stack()))  # stdout: [None]
print(tf.gradients(ya.read(0), xa.read(0)))  # stdout: [None]

# desperate attempt, doesn't work either
za = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1).write(0, xa.read(0) ** 2)
print(tf.gradients(za.read(0), xa.read(0)))  # stdout: [None]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the function `tf.gradients` is a misnomer.  In fact, tf.gradients implements the backprop algorithm; and can only provide gradient calculations between nodes that are connected together in the graph.  Since ya depends in no way on xa, there is no connection and backprop does not work.  The example will provide a gradient:

```
x = tf.Variable(np.array([3]).astype(np.float32), trainable=False)
y = x ** 2
xa = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1).write(0, x)
ya = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1).write(0, xa.read(0))
tf.gradients(ya.stack(), x)
```

but the following will not:

```
y = x ** 2
z = x + 1
tf.gradients(y, z)  # None
```

because there is no DAG path from z to y.

This latter example is more similar to what you're trying to do in your question.

Comment: yes, TensorArray doesn't seem to keep track of the dependencies. Otherwise `za = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1).write(0, xa.read(0) ** 2)
print(tf.gradients(za.read(0), xa.read(0)))` should work

Comment: To be clear, it's not just `TensorArray` that is not keeping track of the dependencies: it's that the backprop algorithm does not work this way (no TensorFlow computation of this sort will work).

Comment: in the last example, za is built from xa, so there is a direct path from xa to za. It's not clear why there is no gradient of za with respect to xa.